# ASP Classic and SQL Server 2008 giving strange response

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, scope-identity

Started getting this error it seems since we upgraded to SQL Server 2008.

When inserting into the db and then returning the identity i get a 'Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal' error.

Here is the code:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO PageFeatures(nPageFeatureFlagId,nPageFeatureFeatureId,nPageFeaturePageId) VALUES(" & nTemplateFlagId & "," & nFeatureId & "," & nPageId & "); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As nPageFeatureId;"
objrs.open SQL,objConn,1,1
    nPageFeatureId = objrs("nPageFeatureId")
objrs.close
```

The insert is working as the record is in the db. It's not returning the id for some reason. It works fine and returns the id when running in SSMS. But ASP can't see the returned id so some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post all the code that is executing?

Comment: Please please read up on SQL Injection Attacks - your code is very prone to that. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Thank you, but we are dealing with possible sql injects further up the page. The value that are in use have already been parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO PageFeatures(nPageFeatureFlagId,nPageFeatureFeatureId,nPageFeaturePageId) VALUES(" & nTemplateFlagId & "," & nFeatureId & "," & nPageId & ");"
objConn.execute(SQL)

Set oReturnValueRS = objConn.Execute("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
nPageFeatureId = oReturnValueRS(0).Value
oReturnValueRS.close : set oReturnValueRS = nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to try moving the recordset on? e.g.

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO PageFeatures(nPageFeatureFlagId,nPageFeatureFeatureId,nPageFeaturePageId) VALUES(" & nTemplateFlagId & "," & nFeatureId & "," & nPageId & "); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() As nPageFeatureId;"
objrs.open SQL,objConn,1,1
    objrs.NextRecordset
    nPageFeatureId = objrs("nPageFeatureId")
objrs.close
```

Raj's comment about SQL injection is still relevant. :)

EDIT: Elaboration is that there are two recordsets in play here. The first is an empty one created by the insert statement, the second one is caused by everything after the semi-colon ;. This is the field you want. So initially, your objrs is attached to the first of its collection of recordsets (not rows in a recordset), you move to the NextRecordset - and you can then deal with that how you please.

Comment: Tried moving the recordset on and got the following error:
Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done